# Create dataframe with equal sample-sizes for each group in dplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I have a dataframe like this:

```
structure(list(event = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), trigger = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The group `trigger` has 97 observations for `TRUE` and 3 for `FALSE`

```
df %>% count(trigger)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  trigger     n
  <lgl>   <int>
1 FALSE      97
2 TRUE        3
```

Now I want to sample both to have 3 (the class `TRUE` does not need any sampling as I want to keep all from the smaller group).

My current approach always looked liked this:

```
set.seed(1)
min = df %>% count(trigger) %>% pull(n) %>% min()

df  %>%
  group_by(trigger) %>%
  sample_n(size=min)
```

But I was wondering if there is any possibility (sure there is...) how to do this all in the mutating.... of the dataframe, without creating the extra variable `min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. It involves referring to `df1` by name in the pipe sequence, which might not be ideal, but it doesn't create an extra variable.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(trigger) %>%
  sample_n(size = min(c(sum(df1$trigger == F), sum(df1$trigger == T))))
```